# I was not able to get a smooth finish on a shower pan, how can I smooth it out?

Tags: tile, shower

I am in the midst of a custom shower project. I am building a shower pan using the "traditional method" which is a concrete pre-slope, then a PVC membrane, then a top mortar bed, and finally tile.

The top mortar bed on my shower pan dried today. Turns out I really am not good at smoothing concrete. I can't lay tile on this. The slope is fine, but there are some dips and humps and a few divots in the pan. The curb is OK but there are a few uneven spots that I need to deal with.

I've been relying on [Floor Elf's website and e-book](http://floorelf.com). The author does a good job describing the right way to do the job. However he is an experienced tile man and I think has glossed over some details that I think I need.

How can I smooth this out?

If I have to redo the top bed I will, but I would like to avoid that entirely. I hesitate to use more bedding mortar as I found that difficult to work with the first time. I feel like I need a 'wetter' mortar. Can I use floor levelling compound? Can I use thinset to fill the low spots in then more thinset to stick the tile?

My technique sucks. How can I improve and get a smooth finish?

How can I maintain the multi-direction slope from the four walls to the offset drain? Sloping along one plane isn't too hard but maintaining a slope along two planes has proven tricky.

How can I lay out a smooth frame or reference line for mortar work?

Comment: The best screed advice I'm aware of at SE is another answer by (deleted) User27967: [How to level bathroom plywood subfloor before tiling?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49826/how-to-level-bathroom-plywood-subfloor-before-tiling)

Answer (score 1):

Tile setters use an abrasive called a [rub stone](http://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-Tile-Sanding-and-Rubbing-Stone-with-Dual-Grit-Surfaces-10022Q/100037081):
[image]

But you could probably use a sanding block. After making it as flat as you can, apply a layer of thin-set mortar. Before doing this, read up on techniques for using thin-set.

Comment: The stones are easily available, cheap, and effective. A sanding block would be an exercise in futility, IMHO.

Comment: An angle grinder with a diamond coated cup wheel will make short work out of that. If you don't have one, they are a little more than $200. Probably not worth it if you plan to use it once.

Answer (score 1):

Apply thinset to low spots and ride off high spots with a straightedge to even the floor.  A shower floor is not something you want to do over a hard mud surface.  The preferred method is to pull your mud and lay your tile fresh, allowing you to use a beating block (4x6 inch is more than enough) using the block and riding at an angle to the tile beat the floor flat.

The biggest mistake pre-floating the mud is that the drain can be an issue if you cut your mud too high in relation.  I should note that over fresh screed you want your thinset *very* wet as too stiff will pull up patches of mud if you pull a tile.  If you do have to pull a tile when fresh, slide it while using a lifting motion.